# Find free rooms for today using mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

If in a mysql table RESERVATIONS there are RPOM_NUMBER, DATE_ARRIVAL and DATE_DEPARTED

How do I find all the rooms that are available today?

Comment: Are you totally ignoring the time of day with this?

Comment: @andyc Assume that arrival and departing is 12:00

Comment: The problem is that if a room has never been reserved then it's `RPOM_NUMBER` will not be in the `RESERVATIONS` table - so you should have another table holding all your rooms...

Comment: ..Also presumably there can be multiple reservations for the same room so you need to do more than (most of the responders have done) just return rows that do not fall in the **now** range - because this will just return you past and future reservations - and ignore rooms that *are* booked now.

Comment: If this is homework, add the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the rooms that are available at particular moment of time:

```
select RPOM_NUMBER
from RESERVATIONS r
group by RPOM_NUMBER
having not exists (
    select *
    from RESERVATIONS 
    where
       RPOM_NUMBER = r.RPOM_NUMBER and
       now() between DATE_ARRIVAL and DATE_DEPARTED
)
```

Checking the rooms that are available at a given period of time (from **start_time** to **end_time**):

```
select RPOM_NUMBER
from RESERVATIONS r
group by RPOM_NUMBER
having not exists (
    select *
    from RESERVATIONS 
    where
       RPOM_NUMBER = r.RPOM_NUMBER and
       {start_time} <= DATE_DEPARTED and
       {end_time} >= DATE_ARRIVAL
)
```

Comment: How do I insert a record in RESERVATIONS if there is an available room in my preferable date of arrival and departure?

Comment: @mtopia You need to check if the room is available at a particular period of time. If YES then insert. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select RPOM_NUMBER where current_date() not between DATE_ARRIVAL and DATE_DEPARTED;
```

This might be help you. If you can give details table structure with some data then it will be help full to give proper answer.

Comment: @sll Yes: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-between

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RPOM_NUMBER
FROM RESERVATIONS
WHERE (CURRENT_DATE() < DATE_ARRIVAL) OR (CURRENT_DATE() > DATE_DEPARTED)
```

**EDIT:** Answer to comments regarding insert into table

You can put the query above in a subquery and then do INSERT with INNER JOIN on
the returned by subquery data set.

! Not tested a query below, just to show an idea:

```
INSERT INTO RESERVATIONS
SELECT available.RPOM_NUMBER, CURRENT_DATE(), CURRENT_DATE()
FROM RESERVATIONS r
INNER JOIN
 (SELECT RPOM_NUMBER
     FROM RESERVATIONS
     WHERE (CURRENT_DATE() < DATE_ARRIVAL) OR (CURRENT_DATE() > DATE_DEPARTED)
  ) available ON available.RPOM_NUMBER = r.RPOM_NUMBER
```

Comment: If there is availability, how do I insert into reservations?

Comment: @mtopia : see updated answer, sorry for non tested qyery I believe you can arrange it up yourself easily, I have no MySQL in hand

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT RPOM_NUMBER
FROM RESERVATIONS
WHERE (DATE(NOW()) NOT BETWEEN DATE_ARRIVAL AND DATE_DEPARTED)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need another table, maybe called `rooms`, that holds that info. A row in that table might have columns like `room_number`, `is_occupied`, `is_reserved`, `reservation_start_time`, `reserved_for_how_long`, `reserved_by_whom`. Stuff that refers only to the room.

As you have your `reservations` (it *could* be a good, useful table, btw) it's difficult for you to tell whether or not a room is empty or occupied, partly because there's no column for whether or not the guest actually showed up and took the room.

You might also consider a table called `guests` that holds all the info for, well, each guest.

Answer (score 0):

You really need a `ROOMS` table to make this database remotely nice to work with - also with a RPOM_NUMBER (Which I am presuming indentifies a single room).

If you have such a table then this query will give RPOM_NUMBERS free now

```
SELECT RPOM_NUMBER FROM ROOMS WHERE RPOM_NUMBER NOT IN
(SELECT DISTINCT RPOM_NUMBER FROM RESERVATIONS WHERE 
 DATE_ARRIVAL < NOW() AND DATE_DEPARTED > NOW())
```

And this will INSERT a row into RESERVATIONS

```
INSERT INTO RESERVATIONS (RPOM_NUMBER,DATE_ARRIVAL,DATE_DEPARTED) VALUES
 (x, y, z)
```

(where `x`,`y`, and `z` are the `RPOM_NUMBER`, `DATE_ARRIVAL` AND `DATE_DEPARTED` respectively)

This makes no allowance for the specific *time*. You will have to think about when you want a room to show as free. *If it's 1 minute since the departure time, is it free? Or is it being cleaned?*

This also assumes that a reservation will have both an arrival and departure date when inserted. *How do you deal with guest that are on an open-ended stay?*

This SQL isn't tested and not sure if it will work in mySQL - but it will be something very similar.